# Product Rule for $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let g: $\mathbb{R}^m$ → $\mathbb{R}^n$ differentiable and h: $\mathbb{R}^m$ → $\mathbb{R}$ differentiable with $x\in \mathbb{R}^m$.
How to prove product rule that ($hg$)($x$)= $h'(x)g(x) + h(x)g'(x)$

I got to do with this definition:
$$
\lim_{k \to 0} \frac{\lVert g(x+k) - g(x) - g'(x)(k) \rVert}{\lVert k \rVert} = 0
$$
But I cannot sum and subtract $g(x)h(x+k)$ - $g(x)h(x+k)$ as I do in $\mathbb{R}$ because $g(x)h(x+k)$ remains and I can't apply limit again. Is there any trick here?
Thanks!

Comment: x is a vector in Rn or Rm? And h:Rm to R , or to Rn?

Comment: @Ameryr it's Rm...I'm sorry, edited it

Comment: Compute the differential of the function $p(x,y)=x+y$, use/prove the chain rule and apply it to $p(h,g)$.

Comment: The product rule is $$(hg)'(x)=g(x)h'(x)+h(x)g'(x).$$ Also, "$g'(x)(k)$" should be written $g'(x)k.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total derivative of the map $x \mapsto h(x)g(x) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ at $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is defined as the unique linear transformation $(hg)'(x)$ such that
$$\lim_{k \to 0} \frac{\Vert (hg)(x+k)-(hg)(x) -(hg)'(x)(k) \Vert}{\Vert k \Vert} = 0$$
Where $k \in \mathbb{R}^m$. To check that your formula is correct, we consider that for any $x,k \in \mathbb{R}^m$

$\begin{align}
 \Vert (h & g)(x+k) -(hg)(x)-h'(x)(k)g(x)-h(x)g'(x)(k) \Vert \\
& = \Vert (hg)(x+k) - h(x+k)g(x)+h(x+k)g(x)-(hg)(x)-h'(x)(k)g(x)-h(x)g'(x)(k) \Vert \\
& = \Vert h(x+k)(g(x+k)-g(x)) -h(x)g'(x)(k) + (h(x+k)-h(x)-h'(x)(k))g(x) \Vert \\
& \leq \Vert h(x+k)(g(x+k)-g(x)) -h(x)g'(x)(k) \Vert + \Vert (h(x+k)-h(x)-h'(x)(k))g(x)\Vert \\ 
& = \Vert h(x+k)(g(x+k)-g(x) - g'(x)(k)) + (h(x+k)-h(x))g'(x)(k) \Vert \\ & \qquad+ \vert h(x+k)-h(x)-h'(x)(k) \vert \Vert g(x) \Vert \\ 
& \leq |h(x+k)|\|g(x+k)-g(x)-g'(x)(k)\| +|h(x+k)-h(x)|\|g'(x)(k)\| \\ & \qquad  + | h(x+k)-h(x)-h'(x)(k)| \| g(x) \|
\end{align} $

So dividing through by $\|k\|$ and taking the limit as $k \to 0$, the first term goes to zero by the definition of $g'(x)$ and continuity of $h$, the second goes to zero by continuity of $h$ and the fact that $\frac{g'(x)(k)}{\|k\|}=g'(x) \left( \frac{k}{\|k\|} \right)$ is bounded, since linear maps on finite dimensional vector spaces are continuous and the unit sphere is compact, and the third term goes to zero by definition of $h'(x)$, showing that the expression $h'(x)g(x)+h(x)g'(x)$ satisfies the defining equation of $(hg)'(x)$.

Comment: The main formula on the third line is missing "$=0$".

Comment: How do we know h'(x)g(x)+h(x)g'(x) is a linear map? I'm not quite sure how it satisfies the linearity property, since we don't know g(x+k) = g(x)+g(k), for x, k in $\mathbb{R}^m.$

Comment: @platypus17 Recall that the definition of the total derivative is a linear map, so what is meant by $g'(x)$ is "the linear map approximating $g$ at $x$". That does *not* mean $g'$ is a linear map. $g'(x+y)$ is not, in general, related nicely to $g'(x)$ and $g'(y)$. But $g'(x)$ *is* a linear map, i.e. $g'(x)(u+v) = g'(x)(u)+g'(x)(v)$. Since $h$ is real-valued, $h(x) \in \mathbb{R}$, the object $h(x)g'(x)$ is still a linear map. Can you make sense of the corresponding statement for $g(x)h'(x)$? Note $h'(x)(u) = u \cdot \nabla h(x)$.